# How to make a barcode scanner(1D barcodes) app in flutter that uses Laser Scanner of different PDA devices spanning multiple manufacturers?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I am creating a mobile application for scanning bar codes. I will be installing this on many of my Organization's PDAs. The PDAs we have include the brands Honeywell, smartpeak, ZKC. I am using flutter to create this app. So far I have tried the following packages from flutter:

- pda_scanner: ^0.2.9 (https://pub.dev/packages/pda_scanner)
  The documentation for pda-scanner is a bit unclear to me. I tried to use the example code and that
  doesnt works for any of the scanner
- zkc_scanner: ^1.0.1+3 (https://pub.dev/packages/zkc_scanner)
  The zkc_scanner works fine for the ZKC scanner but doesnt works with other brands
- honeywell_scanner: ^2.0.0+4 (https://pub.dev/packages/honeywell_scanner)
  adding honeywell_scanner dependency to pubspec.yaml caused compilation failure

Is there any other package that could help me achieve what I want or any way that I could create my own vendor neutral package that can help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer and it was easier than I expected. You really need to use/build any package, just think of the Scanner as an input like another keyboard. Tap on a TextField to focus then use the SCAN key and scan the bar-code. The scanned bar-code will automatically be sent to the highlighted TextField

Comment: Can you share your code? I've been trying to do the same for a few days and with no success so far.